# How can I switch the active profile to "Dev" in JHipster micro-service app deployed to Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I have a micro-services based JHipster app and have generated a Kubernetes deployment script using the `kubernetes` sub-generator.

I have deployed the app to Azure AKS and have it running smoothly. The current profile it is running with is 'prod'. How can I change the active profile the 'dev' in order to view swagger documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to get the swagger API functional by adding swagger to the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable for all containers' deployment file.

```
spec:
  ...
  containers:
    - name: core-app
      image: myrepo.azurecr.io/core
      env:
        - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: prod,swagger
```

Comment: I confirm that this is the way I intended it to be used when I coded this feature in JHipster. You should never enable the dev profile outside of your local machine.

Comment: @PierreBesson i'm running the app on heroku and I need swagger on prod with no auth; I have added swagger profile to mvn build parameters, to SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE variable and enabled all swagger related urls in SecurityConfiguration.java, but still getting the swagger index page not able to load neither swagger-ui/dist/css/typography.css nor swagger-resources/configuration/ui and getting redirect there. Should I enable it somewhee in angular configs part or not?

Comment: @PierreBesson I'm sorry, I have forgotten the Procfile used for heroku which actually drives the profiles used. It had no mention of swagger, that's why

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is here because want to google out why the swagger isn't enabled on prod in heroku installation despite of setting it into `application-prod.yml`, `application-heroku.yml`, `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` env variable, `mvn` start-up parameters in `MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS` env variable in `heroku:config` custom env variables...

It looks like the actual profile that will be used by the heroku prod run is in `Procfile`.

Comment: I think you might need to open a new question for that as it is entirely different than the one asked here.

Comment: Right, but I was supposed it to be the same, until got realized that heroku case it something different, that's why I reached this question :) Hope my comment will help people got faced exactly my case